# MassTransit3 with temporary Queue

Tags: masstransit

I have a webfarm with webgardens, I want that every process gets notified when an event is raised from other processes, this event is mostly used to update internal caches, eg if a process updates a 'customer', all other processes should get notified about that.

Each process creates a Bus with RabbitMQ, then I setup a single endpoint named randomly where I register my consumers, this seems to work, anyway at the end of the day I find lots of dead queues inside RabbitMQ, for the recycled processes.

I tried to use the temporary queue for this purpose but I do not know how to publish an event to the bus and have my consumers automatically connected to it, I have tried to use the ConnectXX methods but they do not setup all the required bindings in RabbitMQ.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a temporary queue:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, ec => { ... })
```

Comment: Forgive me for being obtuse, but that looks identical to the code I'd use to create a persistent queue. What am I missing?